# Maven Jetty plugin stopPort and stopKey missing or invalid

Tags: java, maven, maven-jetty-plugin

I am learning Maven and have encountered a problem. When I try to do mvn clean install with my webapp i get the error saying that parameters stopPort and stopKey are missing or invalid. Here is what pom.xml looks like:

```xml
    <plugin>
       <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>6.1.17</version>
       <executions>
         <execution>
            <id>start-jetty</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
              <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
              <stopKey>foo</stopKey>
              <daemon>true</daemon>
            </configuration>
         </execution>
         <execution>
            <id>stop-jetty</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>stop</goal>
            </goals>
         </execution>
       </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Any idea what could cause that? Thx in advance.

Comment: This is pretty much a guess, but could the problem be because your `stopPort` and `stopKey` are only contained in the configuration of the `run` goal? If you moved that configuration to before the `executions` section does it work? An example can be seen here: https://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Maven+Jetty+Plugin#MavenJettyPlugin-Automaticexecutionoftheplugin

Comment: Awww.. how I could have missed that! Worked fine - thank you! +1

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. Have added it as a proper answer, so that others can easily find it, should they run into the same problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you have only defined the `stopPort` and `stopKey` configuration in the `run` goal. This configuration needs to be moved to be outside the `execution` section.

So your pom would now be:

```xml
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>6.1.17</version>
   <configuration>
       <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
       <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
       <stopKey>foo</stopKey>
   </configuration>
   <executions>
     <execution>
        <id>start-jetty</id>
        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <daemon>true</daemon>
        </configuration>
     </execution>
     <execution>
        <id>stop-jetty</id>
        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>stop</goal>
        </goals>
     </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```